# Indexed, not submitted in sitemap and site map not getting recrawaled : next js

Tags: google-search-console, next.js

I have this website which has lot of dynamic URLs, so I want Googlebot to revisit my sitemap every few days.  However, my site map have not been crawled for a long time now or new pages from it indexed.

`server-sitemap.xml` was crawled on Jan 19 when I published the site. I removed the sitemap and re-added it in search console hoping it will change to today's date. Still it's not changing.

[image]

Only 17 pages are getting indexed that and it says those URLs are not in the site map, even though there are more than 40 URLs in sitemap.
What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

The site is not crawlable due to some issue.

[image]

Comment: Related: [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: yes i have read the site map paradox many times an i am not relying on sitemaps any more but dont u think 2 months is more than enough for a home page to be indexed by the bing  site @MaximillianLaumeister

Comment: and the site being shown in google was made to crwal manuuly by me . if i havnt done that i think the site would not have indexed by google also by now

Answer (score 2):

Sitemap is not a generally useful signal, despite what classical SEO claims.

If you want pages indexed, you first have to make sure they're crawlable organically. Bots often ignore sitemap entries that they can't find organically from the site.

You should think of sitemap as a limiting factor, not empowering. I often ask client to delete their sitemaps and proceed without them when they're struggling with setting up things properly. And your sitemap is exactly the one I would suggest removing.

Comment: so becouse of siteamap my site is not getting indexed?

Comment: no, your site doesn't get indexed because of overall quality reasons and you don't fix them with sitemap.

Comment: can u walk me throguh what are the quality imporovemnt i must make in oder my site to get indexed

Comment: That's a separate question. But in short: you do your typical white-hat seo optimizing texts, markup, meta, linking, backlinks, etc.